# Swift iOS: Facebook SDK Login button doesn't change to logout after login

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook-login, logout

I'm trying to implement Facebook's login / logout functionality to my iOS app in swift. I have followed the exact instructions from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios. When I run my app, the login button works just fine. After the login screen disappears, the login button is still present and has not been switched out by the logout button.

What I find strange is that the function `loginButton` does not print out anything after printing "Logged in":

```
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
    print("Logged in")

    if error == nil {
        let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)

        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential, completion: { (user, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error.debugDescription)
            } else {
                print("succes")
            }
        })

    } else {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

If I change the location of the credential declaration in function `loginButton` to the top, I get the following error:

[EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlFSe.png) (reputation too low to post image)

Anyone experiencing the same problem?

Comment: Run in simulator or device?

Comment: I have run the app in the simulator using xcode

Comment: Please check in device. Because logout is not working in simulator. Otherwise reset simulator.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much

Comment: Hey @CarlAndreasJulsvoll was the issue fixed by resetting the emulator or running the code on an actual device? I am having the same exact issue.

Comment: I run the code on the actual device